# Controlling multiple custom tools from an array

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a simple WinForms GUI that utilizes multiple (~50) of the same custom tool. I have the custom tools imported just fine and is part of my main form. My problem is I'd like a elegant way of handling each custom tool property (ie BackColor, Text, Visible, Enable, etc).

The tool is simple; it has a couple labels on it and each has some strings I use for storing values. I want to be able to control these labels on the custom tool at will without typing up huge amounts of code.

I have a textbox on my Form1 Design that controls the number of custom tools I want enabled and visible, but I cannot figure out a good method to control it. Do I explicitly put 50 custom tools into an array of some sort? If so, how? Since it's a custom tool, I cannot make `CustomToolName[] customTools = new CustomToolName[50]` for example. I've racked my head around this and can't figure out a way without making a really ugly and long solution.

Any suggestions? How would you do this?

EDIT: The List suggestion works. I'm able to control them by using a `List<UserControl> CustomTool = new List<UserControl>();` and then adding each custom tool to the list. A small test of CustomTool[0].Visible = false; worked. I can control them with for loops as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why can't you make a `CustomToolName[]`?

Comment: If its dynamic, why not have a `List<CustomToolName>`? I don't understand the restriction on collections.

Answer (score 0):

This a classic usage of Polymorphism!!! Create an array or list of Base class and put all your controls inside. Run throuhg the list with loop and use properties. If you need to get sepecial properties that only specific classes have, verify type of current object. Something like that:

```
 List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();

        //Add controls

        foreach (Control item in controls)
        {
            item.Visible = true;

            if (item is MyCustomButton)
            {
                ((MyCustomButton)item).CustomProperty = "123";
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, however I'm still a bit confused. I can't seem to modify their properties without explicitly stating them (example: myControl1.AuthorizationCode = "6564564";). I have 50 controls... and I'd like to be able to put controls[1] = "6564564"; Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Only if base class have this property